# What is the valid format for the name of a querystring parameter?

Tags: url

The question is clear itself what it says. To emphasize, I am not asking about the value of a querystring parameter, as all developers already know, they should be urlencoded.

My question is, what is the format for the "Name" of a queystring parameter? Should it be urlencoded as well, like its value?

Thanks

Comment: As a rule of thumb, generally name parameters like you would name a variable in programming. So use letters and digit, maybe underscore, but not more. There is a formal definition you can look it up if you want to, but what for? A simple test if you are unsure about a specific name: try it and take a look what comes out on the server side.

Comment: I guess there's a misunderstanding here. I don't want to name parameters. The question is about the format of the parameter names. i.e. I don't want to choose a name for a querystring parameter, instead I'd like to know the format by which I can validate a parameter name.

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot read from your question that you want to validate the names. Why would you want to do that? Either the name works or not. You get what you get on the server side, there is absolutely no sense in trying to validate something there.

Comment: Dear friend, suppose you are making a library constituting different classes one of which is a Querystring class. In a method such as Add(name, value), do you want to allow the user to name her querystring parameter anything she wants? That's why I need to validate the name.

Comment: Ah, OK, makes sense. Thanks. Would make made sense too to tell in the question that you want to validate the names and add a hint onto why. Such details really help when you want to get good answers :-) As mentioned before there is a formal definition for this. Since you want to create a library you are interested that. A simple google search shows up the relevant RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986

Answer (score 0):

Actually by try and error (as [arkascha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1248114/arkascha) recommended too) I used such a bizarre querystring example in a page as below:

```
?a!=1&.b=2&:c=3&+d=4&e%20f=4&h.i=5&\j=6&k+l=7
```

And the result I got was this way:

```
a! = 1
e f = 4
.b = 2
:c = 3
 d = 4
h.i = 5
\j = 6
k l = 7
```

So, it seems you can use any characters but plus sign for a querystring parameter name.

Comment: Well, that actually depends in what environment you use. You cannot make a general rule about that! Different browsers and server side components will handle things different. That is why I made a "conservative" suggestion for the naming above.

Comment: That's true. there are differences between browsers and server-side technologies. The browsers might send querystring differently to the server and on the server-side, the framework might process it differently. That's why I'm seeking the correct format or standard for the name of querystring parameters. The question I proposed could be more correct if I had specified a server-side framework, e.g. "What is the format of blah blah blah in ASP.NET or PHP or Ruby, whatever". But I thought the best thing is to see what the standard or rule is on this matter. Thanks for your help.

Comment: See my comment to your question.